# Apply node script to the logs generated by node project

Tags: node.js, logging, intellij-idea, npm

In command line I can successfully run this:

```
npm run start | node myScript.js >> log.log
```

The script is beautifying the logs. I would like to apply the same to some configuration in Intellij IDEA.

My npm run start is used like this:

[image]

but *how to apply the script*?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a wrapper script as Node.js interpreter. Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11774#focus=streamItem-27-714652-0-0 for an example